# Replace within found area

Tags: vim, regex

I have a TSV file who's 8th column is a description column. The description sometimes contains tabs, which I want to escape as `\t`.

I'm currently using the following regex repeated many times:

```
%s#\v([^\t]*\t){8}[^\t]*\zs\t#\\t#
```

However, this is proving too inefficient.

I want to select everything after the 8th column with `/\v([^\t]*\t){8}\zs.*` and then run the simple regex `s#\t#\\t#g` on those areas.

This must be possible. How can it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Match everything after the 7th column as one string (`.*`), then apply the escaping of the tab with an inner `substitute()` function call, invoked via `:help sub-replace-special`:

```
:%s#\v([^\t]*\t){8}[^\t]*\zs.*#\=substitute(submatch(0), '\t', '\\t', 'g')#
```

#### Plugin alternative

My [PatternsOnText plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4602) provides (among others) a `:[range]SubstituteInSearch/{search}/{pattern}/{string}/[flags] [count]` command that simplifies this:

```
:%SubstituteInSearch /\v([^\t]*\t){8}[^\t]*\zs.*/\t/\\t/g
```

Comment: Genius! It works! `submatch(0)` is particularly clever; had me stumped for a few seconds!

Comment: Thanks! Yes, `submatch(0)` contains the entire match, it is the expression equivalent of `\0` (or `&`).